# Integrating Pyjamas with Pinax+Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, pinax, pyjamas

I'm going to start looking into this tomorrow when I begin my project, but could anyone point me in the right direction? (Maybe some integration code and/or a sample Pyjamas interface which uses Pinax as the backend -- all with adequate explanation, if possible? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinax is a collection of django applications. There's nothing specific to integrating pinax and pyjamas more than it is specific to integrating django and pyjamas. So the [pyjamas book](http://pyjs.org/book/output/Bookreader.html#Rest%20of%20the%20World) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this http://code.google.com/p/pyjamas/wiki/DjangoWithPyjamas  link helps you.